# Parent child relationship in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

How can I maintain the parent child relationship in custom post types, so that I have a uniform URL structure? I want to make a URL structure up to 4 levels, e.g.

```
example.com/sponsor-child/disadvantaged-community/gita-magar
```

Is it possible without a plugin? When I go to a single page URL, it ends in 3 levels.

Answer (score 19):

In your `register_post_type` call, make sure you have these arguments:

```
register_post_type(
    'my_post_type',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug'       => 'my_post_type',
            'with_front' => false,
        ),
        'supports' => array(
            'page-attributes' /* This will show the post parent field */,
            'title',
            'editor',
            'something-else',
        ),
        // Other arguments
    )
);
```

Make sure your permalinks are flushed (just visit the Settings > Permalinks page).

Now when you create a new `my_post_type`, just set it's parent to another and it's permalink will look something like:

```
http://example.com/parent-post-type/my-post-type/
```

You can go as many levels as you need.

Comment: Can you give me entire code of creating custom post type with parent child relation and URL level to 4 levels for making uniform structure of URL.

Comment: Works fine for me - technically, there shouldn't be any limit. Have you tested this in a fresh install of WordPress with all plugins disabled, and then flushed permalinks?